# (Bug?Issue) Objects that have changed angle and position, on their own no going back possible

Tags: 3d-view, keyframes, geometry, error, windows

So as you can see my object changed position, its not about keyframes in animation, its not about me having changed them, i was working on an object and on a click all these objects moved away, chair, radio light, and more. I tried to recover last session and even one ive done 1 hour ago and by these version the position of the object changed too, it happend once when i clicked on the left arrow but i just made a CTRL+Z. but again there is only one keyframe in animation so im pretty sure its not about this ( by putting play nothing happends or change), thanks for the help. Have a great day.
Sven [image: This picture is how it is now][image: this is one of the lagged object][image: the position it had before][image: + what my scene was looking like before]

Answer (score 1):

When you this happens to you its because you changed keyframe with the arrow key on a collection, so basically all the collection will change and move randomly.

I might think its an issue with grease pencil being active, so what you have to do is set all your objects transform to 0, take of the automated keys and don't animate them without using the <kbd>I</kbd> button to lock it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don forget using CTRL+A and Apply all transformation like saving ur fil so all ur object will be placed anturally on 0